# error : Element input with attribute type whose value is button must have non-empty attribute value

Tags: html, joomla, virtuemart, w3c-validation

I am using joomla 2.5.8 with virtuemart 2.0.6. Upon w3 validation i get following error's :

> Element input with attribute type whose value is button must have
>   non-empty attribute value `<input type="button"class="quantity-controls quantity-minus" />`. Element input with
>   attribute type whose value is button must have non-empty attribute
>   value.

Comment: Read all words and try to understand them. The message is clear. Also nowdays IMHO validating after w3c is in most of the cases a lost of time.

Comment: You should provide the relevant HTML in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a `<button>` tag.

```
<button type="button" id="myButton">Click</button>
```

It is a valid markup for HTML5. If you need this button submit a form you can change the type to `submit`.

```
<button type="submit" id="myButton">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Marico.. This is another great saver. Yes it worked.

Answer (score 8):

You must provide a value attribute for your button.

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Here" />
```

if you don't want to display anything in it then use **`value="&#160;"`**

Comment: value is populated using <?php tag. i will try to use if block for php block and update you.

Comment: Thank you Salam. I added the ascii value in - If block and it worked.